# TableView is not loading data?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

In my Map application I have segment controller on main screen and using that I have Map View & tableview(both are UIView). I have tried everything but my data is not loading in my tableview. Here is my tableview code. Here marker is attribute in my xml file which contain Showroom name and Iam able to parse this.
.h file

```
@interface HViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>    {      
 UITableView *_tableView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *_tableView;
@end
```

.m file

**Edited** = with ViewWillAppear,viewDieLoad, segement action method

```
 @synthesize tableView;
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
appDelegate = (HAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication   sharedApplication] delegate];

[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:)

           forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

   }

 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
 {
self._tableView.rowHeight = 80.0;

    [_tableView reloadData];
 }

 -(void)segmentAction:(id)sender;{
UISegmentedControl* segCtl = sender ;

if( [segCtl selectedSegmentIndex] == 0 )

{
    NSLog(@"segmentAction mapView");
    mapView.hidden = NO;
    _tableView.hidden = YES;
    //[ self.view addSubview:mapView] ;    // adding view to segmentindex 0

}

if( [segCtl selectedSegmentIndex] == 1 )

{
    NSLog(@"segmentAction _tableview");
    _tableView.hidden = NO;
    mapView.hidden = YES;
    //[ self.view addSubview:_tableview] ;

}
}
  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
   return 1;
   }
  // Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section   {
NSLog(@"appDelegate.markers _tableview");

return [appDelegate.markers count];
   }

   //method to print row(showroom count on Header)
   - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:  (NSInteger)section {

 if(section == 0)
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"ShowRooms[%d]",  @"Showroom format"), [appDelegate.markers count]];
   }

 // Customize the appearance of table view cells.
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSUInteger const kShowroomNameLabelTag = 2;
UILabel *ShowroomNameLabel = nil;

  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;   

    ShowroomNameLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 1, 300,   20)] autorelease];
    ShowroomNameLabel.tag = kShowroomNameLabelTag;
    ShowroomNameLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:ShowroomNameLabel];
NSLog(@"UITableViewCell.markers _tableview");

}
else 
    {
    ShowroomNameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kShowroomNameLabelTag];


}   

marker *aMarker = [appDelegate.markers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//ShowroomNameLabel.text = aMarker.name;
ShowroomNameLabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ShowroomName= %@",   aMarker.name];


return cell;
}
```

In my tableview Header it shows data count correctly but not showing data.
I have connected delegate,datasource,_tableview to fileOwner of the HViewController in which I have put above code. Plz suggest something where I am wrong. I am parsing XML file and getting data in console alos I can show it on Map. But I am not able to load data in my tableview.
[image]

Comment: I just get best answer for above problem on following link:) Must see....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239543/tableview-is-not-showing-data. It was very small solutions which makes big difference. Thanks Louis and salo.dm for follow up. salo.dm has helped me to solve some buggs in below answer. thanks again for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving `[_tableView reloadData]` to `viewWillAppear`.

[UITableViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007523) reloads the table view's data in `viewWillAppear`, not `viewDidLoad`.  I can't tell you the exact reason for which this would make a difference, though I can think of several.  Anyway, it's worth a try.

EDIT:
RESPONSE TO COMMENTS

1. If `titleForHeaderInSection:` is being called, then there is a data source connected to a table view. So, the problem is not a lack of a data source connection.
2. I am guessing you have 2 table views in your .xib file:  a large one & a short one below it. The large table view is not connected to the data source, so it just displays blank lines.  The short table view *is* connected to the data source.  But, it is just tall enough for a header and has no space left to display any cells.  Thus, `titleForHeaderInSection:` is called, but `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is not because there is no space to display any cells.
   Note that this is just a guess, but it is the only scenario I can think of that would cause the behavior you described. The code you posted looks ok, although a bit more complicated than necessary.
3. There is no question that `reloadData` should be in `viewWillAppear`.  That's where the Apple engineers put it when they created the UITableViewController class.  So, to put it elsewhere, you have to believe you know better than they do.

Comment: I have tried your soltion it doesnt work. I check my - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 } method is not getting called by setting breakpoint or NSLoging. How can I resolve this???

Comment: Also the following method shows data count at the bottom of tableview - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:  (NSInteger)section {

 if(section == 0)
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"ShowRooms[%d]",  @"Showroom format"), [appDelegate.markers count]];
   }
:(:(:(

Comment: yeah your guess is correct... by mistakenly I had two tableview which I did not observed before. The one tableview I have deleted. This solve my one problem. Now I am getting data count on the above. But not getting the data to display:(

Comment: still my cellForRowAtIndexPath: not getting called by setting breakpoint...I have reconnected everything again with deleting one unnecessary tableview as u suggested. Only Getting data count at the top with blank list

Comment: Did you move `reloadData` back to `viewWillAppear`?  Is `numberOfRowsInSection:` getting called?

Comment: numberOfRowsInSection: getting called. & also move reloadData to viewWillAppear. No success yet...see my image

Comment: I think I got it.  Try this.  Delete the line `_tableView = [[UITableView alloc]init];`.  You can also delete the following two lines if you make sure the data source & delegate are hooked up correctly in Interface Builder.  Leaving those 2 lines shouldn't have any effect, but if it still doesn't work, also delete them.

Comment: The problems is the following.  Interface Builder creates a table view for you.  But, afterwards, in `viewDidLoad` you create a new table view & set the ivar to the new table view, deleting the connection to the Interface Builder table view.  But, you don't call `addSubview:` to add the new table view.  So, the new table view is not displayed at all, while the Interface Builder table is no longer connected to IBOutlet ivar.  In summary, you do not need to alloc/init a table view in code if you already created it in Interface Builder.

Comment: I have created again new module. but trust me it is again not loading data. Showing same screen like I have pasted above. Well I am moving ahead for another functional module simultaneously:(:(. Thanks for the follow up. I wl paste answer if I solve this query

Comment: Did you delete `_tableView = [[UITableView alloc]init];`?  The odd thing is that the title is being displayed, but that could be from another piece of leftover code, or a leftover object in IB.

Comment: Code looks good now.  There must be something somewhere else affecting it.  (You might try changing `[_tableView reloadData]` to `[self._tableView reloadData]`, though I don't think that would have an effect.)  Well, at least you fixed 3 different bugs that prevented the table from loading properly.

Comment: [self._tableView reloadData] did this. no success:(

Comment: I'm all out of ideas.  I can't see any more errors here.  Bug must be elsewhere.  You may want to recheck the IB connections, or you may want to start the project over again if it's small enough.  Could be some leftover piece of code or a leftover object in IB.

Comment: Hey salo.dm........Actully data getting loading but I cant see data in tableview. But When I am calling ModelviewController on other toolbar button and after dissmissing the ModelviewController I can see the data in tableview.  Do you have any idea to show data as soon as web service called.

Comment: I have crated new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239543/tableview-is-not-showing-data